# do/while loop with cin.getline parsing to string doesn't compare values to break it

Tags: c++, do-while, getline

So I have this type of "menu" in a do/while loop

```
    do {
        cout << "Press 0 to export IDs, exit to exit, or any key to continue to menu:\n";
        cin.getline(choice, sizeof(choice));
        if (strcmp(choice, "0") == 0) {
            planesManager.exportIds(idsArray, arrSize);
            cout << "Would you like to Sort them?[y/n]\n";
            cin >> choice;
            if (strcmp(choice, "y") == 0) {
                int low = 0;
                int high = arrSize - 1;
                quickSort(idsArray, low, high);
            }
            cout << "Would you like to print them?[y/n]\n";
            cin >> choice;
            if (strcmp(choice, "y") == 0) {
                printArray(idsArray, arrSize);
            }
        }

        do {
            cout << ">Would you like to create, search, edit, or go back?\n";
            cin >> choice;
            if (strcmp(choice, "create") == 0) {
                planesManager.createEntry();
            } else if (strcmp(choice, "search") == 0) {
                planesManager.searchEntry();
            } else if (strcmp(choice, "edit") == 0) {
                planesManager.editEntry();
            }
        } while (strcmp(choice, "back") != 0);
        cin.ignore();
    } while (strcmp(choice, "exit") != 0);
```

However, when typing "exit" on the first input, it doesn't exit the loop and goes into the inner one. Where is the issue and what would be possible solutions?

p.s. When running only the inner do/while loop it works correctly.

Comment: a do-while loop is always entered at least once. Do you want a `while(condition) {...}` loop?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number yes, I want it to enter once so I can register user input. If the user types "exit" I want the loop to break.

Comment: @Nik Then you should do exactly that. `if(userEnters "exit") break;`. You just need to convert this from pseudo code to proper C++. Btw. Is there any reason why you don't use `std::string`?

Comment: @churill Yes, this is from uni and I have to use char array or make my own string class which I can use. I'm almost done with it. On the matter of this question, why isn't my code working? On the inner do-while, it properly compares and breaks the loop if the user types "back". p.s. - I can make it with an if clause, or just keep one do-while loop and add another "branch" that would be the option to "sort" which will call the function. However, I want to keep them separated as the inner menu is to be for crud operations(yes, no delete, ik, might add it) and the outer one for export/sort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same `choice` buffer to manage both loops.

The outer loop's `while` check is not reached until the inner loop is finished first, and the inner loop only breaks when `choice` is `"back"`. So, by the time the outer loop's `while` check is reached, `choice` will never be `"exit"`.

Try this instead:

```
do {
    cout << "Press 0 to export IDs, exit to exit, or any key to continue to menu:\n";
    cin.getline(choice, sizeof(choice));

    if (strcmp(choice, "exit") == 0) break; // <-- move this here!

    if (strcmp(choice, "0") == 0) {
        planesManager.exportIds(idsArray, arrSize);
        cout << "Would you like to Sort them?[y/n]\n";
        cin >> choice;
        if (strcmp(choice, "y") == 0) {
            quickSort(idsArray, 0, arrSize - 1);
        }
        cout << "Would you like to print them?[y/n]\n";
        cin >> choice;
        if (strcmp(choice, "y") == 0) {
            printArray(idsArray, arrSize);
        }
    }

    do {
        cout << ">Would you like to create, search, edit, or go back?\n";
        cin >> choice;
        if (strcmp(choice, "create") == 0) {
            planesManager.createEntry();
        } else if (strcmp(choice, "search") == 0) {
            planesManager.searchEntry();
        } else if (strcmp(choice, "edit") == 0) {
            planesManager.editEntry();
        }
    } while (strcmp(choice, "back") != 0);

    cin.ignore();

} while (true);
```